# Using =if in excel Dax

Tags: excel, dax

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Final Prod Usage Measure:=IF(MasterPartList[Prod Source]=TRUE(), [Standard Flagged], [Custom Flaggged])
```

Comment: You need to state what the actual problem is that you are encountering.

Comment: And describe the shape of the report you are trying to build and how you expect this calc to come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fact that you're using a column reference in your IF(), when this measure is likely to be evaluated in a filter context that has more than one [Prod Source] in context.

Most likely you want to do the following or something similar with an *X() function:

```
SUMX(
    VALUES( MasterPartList[Prod Source] )
    ,IF(
        MasterPartList[Prod Source]
        ,[Standard Flagged]
        ,[Custom Flaggged]
)
```

This creates a row context based on the distinct values of [Prod Source]. Since you expect [Prod Source] to be a Boolean value, no need to explicitly test against TRUE().

If this doesn't do what you want, that's because I'm entirely guessing based on similar mistakes I've seen other people make with that sort of idiom. I'll emphasize that this is a guess, because you've not shared any details whatsoever about what you're trying to do.